# Ocaml - 2 FOR loops

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to figure out how ocaml works. For example the 8 queen problem. I need to make a function T (int*int) array -> bool that returns true if the position is attacked by other queen. For example an array is entered:

```
T[|(1,2);(4,3);(5,6);(2,7);(3,6);(2,8);(1,4);(2,2)|] (numbers represent vertical and horizontal positions:
```

returns

```
bool array =[|false,true,true,false.....]
```

I didn't check, but i hope you get the point and are familiar with this problem. 
I tried solving this with 2 FOR loops but the return value confuses me. Is ocaml working differently?

Comment: It's hard to say anything without seeing at least some of your code. OCaml works differently from many other languages--that's why people study it in school :-)

Comment: You could also give us an idea of the output you were expecting so that we can explain why and how it differs.

Comment: for loops don't sound like an idomatic way to do this in OCaml. Functional programming typically doesn't use such loops.

Comment: for loops return unit. So the expected return value would be `(): unit` or if you used Array.map then `[|(); (); (); (); (); (); (); ();|]`

Answer (score 0):

OCaml is a perfectly common and normal programming language that works the same as any other popular compiled languages, including C, Pascal, or Basic. Speaking more formally it is a strict (i.e., with normal evaluation strategy) language that perfectly supports imperative procedural paradigm. It uses C runtime and programs, written in OCaml, runs directly on your CPU.

How OCaml "works", i.e., what is the meaning of different language constructs is clearly defined by the OCaml manual. It is recommended to read it before you plug your computer in and start coding in OCaml:) For example, this is an excerpt from the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html), describing how the `for` loop works:

> The expression `for name =  expr1 to  expr2 do  expr3 done` first evaluates the expressions `expr1` and `expr2` (the boundaries) into integer values n and p. Then, the loop body expr3 is repeatedly evaluated in an environment where `name` is successively bound to the values n, n+1, …, p−1, p. The loop body is never evaluated if n > p.
>
> The expression `for name =  expr1 downto  expr2 do  expr3 done` evaluates similarly, except that `name` is successively bound to the values n, n−1, …, p+1, p. The loop body is never evaluated if n < p.
>
> In both cases, the whole for expression evaluates to the unit value `()`.

So don't try to shuffle off the blame on the language :) It's perfectly normal, no surprises here. Focus on your code, and on your understanding of the problem.